# Camel http4 component 411 Bad Content-Length

Tags: apache-camel, http-status-code-411

The route :

```
  from("direct:start")
  .setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME, constant("iso-8859-1"))
  .process(new Processor() {            
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
          Message m = exchange.getOut();
          m.setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody());
          m.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethods.POST);
          m.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip" );
          m.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_LENGTH, m.getBody(byte[].class).length );
          m.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");
          m.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING, "iso-8859-1");
          m.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate");        
        }
    })
  .marshal().gzip()
  .to("http4://remote.com/path")
  .unmarshal().gzip();
```

What I am sending :

```
String body = "<?xmlversion=\"1.0\"encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><theXml></theXml>";
producer.sendBody(body);
```

I am getting

> HTTP operation failed invoking http://remote.com/path with statusCode: 411

What is missing/wrong with this route ?

**EDIT**

The correct route would be

```
  from("direct:start")
  .process(new Processor() {            
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
          Message m = exchange.getOut();
          m.setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody());
          m.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethods.POST);
          m.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip" );
          m.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");        
        }
    })
  // http4 takes care of compressing/decompressing gzip
  .to("http4://remote.com/path")
```

But now I have another problem : the remote server does not handle "Transfer-Encoding: Chuncked" Which seems to be the default way camel-http4 does it. 
And i can't figure out how to turn *Chunked* off.

See next question [How to turn off “Transfer-Encoding Chuncked” in Camel-http4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382490/how-to-turn-off-transfer-encoding-chuncked-in-camel-http4)

Comment: Hmm.  The HTTP status code is pretty clear -- the server is expecting a Content-Length header... but you are clearly setting one in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the content length from the length of the unencoded data. It should probably be the length of the transmitted data. Refer to this SO question:
[content-length when using http compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819280/content-length-when-using-http-compression)

By the way, do you really need to gzip with the data format?
There is a Unit test in camel sending GZIPed data.

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-http4/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpCompressionTest.java

Comment: You are right, it is not needed ! now it is ok but then I have found another problem... The remote server does not handle "Transfer-Encoding: chunked", but I can't figure out how to disable it in camel-http4