# Reliably test if a server gzips content

Tags: apache, google-chrome-devtools, gzip, mod-deflate, web-performance

I seem to be getting different results in testing whether the content is served gzipped via Apache's `mod_deflate`.

I test the same URL and on one PC I have `Content-Encoding:gzip` present in response headers, on a different PC that has *almost* identical set up (version of Windows, browser versions, etc) I do not and the page loads more slowly and has a bigger size. The request header `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch, br` is present in both cases.

1. Can someone recommend a reliable way of testing that the content is gzipped?
   By reliable I mean - other than Chrome Dev Tools.
2. Why is it that some users may have the full content even though they request for a gzipped one? Is it server-related or client-related? How can I ensure that 100% of my users get gzipped content?

Comment: Maybe the second PC is behind a proxy (could be a transparent one) that did something to the headers.

Comment: @wOxxOm, nice idea, although when I test another URL (like google.com, for example) the results are identical, both PCs get it gzipped

Comment: Sticking with the proxy suggestion Try a site that's not on https as this usually prevent's proxies from reading the content. [bing](http://www.bing.com/) perhaps.

Comment: @SteveE. I've just checked bing.com, and indeed - it is not gzipped on _that_ machine. However, I did test it on a website of mine (https) and it isn't gzipped either, so in my case protocol sometimes doesn't matter. Any idea on how to set it up so that proxies couldn't tinker with it? Anyways, this seems like the internet provider has got that 'clever' way of increasing the traffic volume, especially if a client doesn't have an unlimited package :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can someone recommend a reliable way of testing that the content is gzipped? By reliable I mean - other than Chrome Dev Tools.**

**[Answer]** - A reliable way to test would be to find out the size of the content retrieved from server and compare with the content length received. As per this post ([content-length when using http compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819280/content-length-when-using-http-compression)), the content length will be the size of compressed content.

If the content is text, the compression ratio will be 3:1 or more. However if you are sending a compressed image it will be lot less. In any case if the compression is working, it will be greater than 1:1.

For test setup, you can host a set of test data like text files, images on apache with knowledge on their sizes. May be the name of the file could be their size like 1024bytes.txt. On client side, you can send a request to retrieve the data and compare the response headers (Content-Length) to check the size of the content. You can automate this using tools such as mocha & chai.

**Why is it that some users may have the full content even though they request for a gzipped one? Is it server-related or client-related? How can I ensure that 100% of my users get gzipped content?**

**[Answer]** - You can only ensure this from server side. There will be client side limitations and bugs. For e.g. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/871205/internet-explorer-may-not-decompress-http-content-when-you-visit-a-web-site. As you can see, a windows bug can cause compression to fail. This or a similar bug can probably explain why you see a different behavior on a different machine.

**How do we fix this?**

You can compare your test setup with a reliable data provider. In your case, you did verify it with www.bing.com. Once you verify that your test setup and client is working correctly with a reliable source, test it with your apache server and certify.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the issue is a caching proxy as discussed in the comments.

There are a couple of options.

1. Apache can add http headers to the content which informs caches not to store content. Put the following into your VirtualHost block

   Header set Cache-Control "private"

   No promises that the above will work, it's an advisory which may be ignored by a proxy.
2. A more reliable way, would be to use HTTPS, this prevents almost all proxies from reading anything other than the host name so it's impossible for them to act as a cache. SSL certificates are pretty cheap, but you could test for free using a self signed certificate first.

There are instructions for creating a [self signed cert here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/10176685#10176685) Then copy your VirtualHost block and paste a new one changing the port to 443 and adding the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

     .... Existing config

     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key

</VirtualHost>
```

As a final point, I would note that if an organisation has implemented a caching proxy. The purpose of that is possibly to improve performance for their users. The best way to know for sure if a technical change is improving speed for end users is to measure it. The Chrome developer tools include a network monitor which include page load timings and lots of other interesting details.