# PHP file transfer an Excel xls file from the server to a local PC doesn't work

Tags: php, excel, file-transfer

I have an Excel 2013 xls file on my server and I would like it to download to my local Windows download directory.

```
$filename = 'test.xls';

$file_path = $filename;

if (file_exists($file_path)) {
    // Header setzen
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));

    readfile($file_path);

    exit;
} else {
    echo 'File not found.';
}
```

The download works just fine but the xls file is not readable. The error message is that Excel can't open the file because the fileformat is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe this helps?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487365/http-header-for-downloading-microsoft-word-and-excel-files

Comment: Check there's no extra content in the file after it's downloaded (e.g. whitespace, or HTML or something that's gone into the file when it shouldn't, via your PHP script). Also, do you really need all those headers? Content-Type and Content-Disposition should be sufficient in most cases. Use the minimum you can get away with, in case some of the others are causing an issue. Content-Length in particular can be unhelpful sometimes

Comment: @ADyson Content-Length should not be problematic, provided it gives the _correct_ number. Leaving it out completely, would mean the browser would not be able to show a proper download progress bar any more (might not be _that_ relevant with typical PDF file sizes, but something to at least consider.)

Comment: Besides the already mentioned factors of possible white space or HTML output, also make sure your PHP script itself is saved without a BOM.

Comment: I got rid of all the unwanted headers. I can't find any whitespace or HTML in the filename. The xls file is on the server and the script is just downloading it to the pc. What else coul I look for?

Comment: @CBroe `provided it gives the correct number`...which was kind of my point, I guess :-)

Comment: `I can't find any whitespace or HTML in the filename`, no, not in the filename, in the downloaded file itself, was what we meant. Open it in a text editor and look for anything that looks like it shouldn't be there (compare it to the original on the server if you need to)

Comment: @ADyson agreed, Content-Length could be an issue indeed, if additional Content-Encoding was applied (outside of the PHP script, on the web server level perhaps) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819303/1427878

Comment: Looking at the downloaded file with an Editor: the file is empty. Not so the original file.

Comment: Ok. Odd. Do you have PHP error logging enabled? Are there any errors in the log? I wonder about some sort of permissions issues, or similar.

Comment: No I have not PHP error logging enabled. I don't know how to do that :-(

Comment: Well did you try to google it then? You could just type "php enable error logging", in your favourite search engine. Shouldn't be hard to find out. You always need that enabled, so you can debug your code effectively.

Comment: I'm completely lost. :-( Do I need to enable PHP error logging on the server or my XAMPP php.ini file?

Comment: Huh? Enable it on the machine where this PHP code gets executed. Is the PHP code located on your local machine, or on another server?

Comment: It's on the server.

Comment: So then you need to change the logging settings on that server. If it's a shared hosting account, logging is probably enabled already, and you just need to locate the log file. If it's not, or you can't find the file, speak to your hosting company - on a shared host you won't be able to change the php.ini file yourself, most likely.

Comment: P.S. Another thing you can do, obviously, is put the Excel file and the PHP on your local machine, and test and debug your code using your local XAMPP server. Then once you're sure it's correct and working, you can upload it to the real server. That's normally how people develop and test their code, as it's usually much easier.

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I will go to the hosting company. Good idea with the local XAMPP. I use the PhpSpreadsheet library to create my own Excel spreadsheet. Is there a way to directly save the created xls file on my local download directory? Than I would not neet the download it.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. To transfer a file from a server to your local directory will always involve downloading it in some fashion. If you are running PHP on the server, then it can only write data to the server, or to the output of the script (i.e. back to the browser, in the HTTP response). It can't save files directly to a user's local disk, it has no knowledge or visibility of that - and can you imagine the security implications, and the carnage that would ensue if web applications could do that!?

Comment: Thank you very much for your explantion. That helps me a lot. I'm waiting now to hear from the hosting company.

Comment: I got the confirmation from he hosting company that PHP error logging is enabled. Looking at the error logfile, there is no evidence of en error what so ever. Looking with en Editor at the original and the copied xls file, they look completely different. The copied file has two empty lines at the very beginning. What is the propper PHP code to log any other errors?

Comment: PHP will log errors automatically once it's configured, you don't have to do anything extra. But if you're getting blank space at the start of the file, I'd look for blank space / lines in the relevant PHP files (i.e. the one which runs this code, and any that are `include`d or `require`d by it) before, or between the `<?php...?>` blocks, and/or `echo` statements which print empty stuff. _Any_ content which the script outputs - even empty lines by accident - during the response will become part of the downloaded artefact.

Comment: WOW, after deleting the 2 empty lines right after <?php in my code, did the trick. It works now as expected. :-) Thank you ever so much for your help and particular for your patience. I really do appreciate it a lot.